# Reactjs Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' bundle.js:1

Tags: reactjs

I am getting below error. I tried to follow steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541165/webpack-error-bundle-js1-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) post but looks like its not relevant in my case because I am not using babel.
Its complaining about all 3 .js files bundle.js, vendor.js, main.chunk.js
I am new to react. Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' bundle.js:1
```

Here's my index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my .env

```
PORT=8080
PUBLIC_URL=http://reporting-front-end.p-lg6gp.c-f5nnh.use2.nonprod.cps.aws.cloud.bank-dns.com/cctra-reporting
```

Here's my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import registerServiceWorker from 'react-service-worker';

import Client from 'aws-appsync';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { Rehydrated } from "aws-appsync-react";
import AppSync from './AppSync';

const client = new Client({
  url: AppSync.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSync.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: 'API_KEY',
    apiKey: AppSync.aws_appsync_apiKey
  }
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
      <App />
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
registerServiceWorker();
```

Here's my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "reporting-front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/cctra-reporting",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.12",
    "@usb-shield/design-tokens": "^3.18.1",
    "@usb-shield/react-button": "^1.0.4",
    "@usb-shield/react-divider-line": "^2.0.0",
    "@usb-shield/react-dropdown": "^2.0.0",
    "@usb-shield/react-icons": "^1.0.3",
    "@usb-shield/react-tabs": "^1.10.2",
    "@usb-shield/themes": "^0.6.11",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.1",
    "aws-appsync-react": "^4.0.7",
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-native": "^0.59.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-service-worker": "^0.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

Here's the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Here's the network tab in browser
[image]

Here's response from bundle.js

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you’re hosting in a sub directory. Did you try to set the “homepage” property in package.json and rebuild?

Comment: I did. I put "homepage": "/build", but still the same issue. Just to clarify build folder gets created when I run npm build in dockerfile. That's why you don't see it in the folder structure.

Comment: Your sub folder is “/cctra-reporting” though not “/build”.

Comment: Thanks. I just added "homepage": "/cctra-reporting", but still the same issue. I have updated the package.json in my question. Also have uploaded the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Please also post a screenshot of the Network tab showing the request/response for the bundle.js file.

Comment: What does the response for bundle.js look like?

Comment: I have uploaded the response from bundle.js

Comment: The file bundle.js is returning an HTML file in the browser, which is the problem. Why did you manually add all of the JS script files to index.html? The build process should handle that for you.

Comment: I didn't manually add it. Its being added by the build process. I copied the content from the page source of the web page to this post. That's why the JS script file are mentioned in index.html. Sorry, I thought index.html will be exactly same in the backend one.  Let me update that to the index.html in my repo.

Comment: Did you find anything related to this? I am getting the same issue ..

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, this error is because of `package.json` conflict. If you initiate a new `node` project inside a existing react folder, it might give this error. If this is the case, try NOT to use `npm init` or `npm init -y`